# What happens after dragging and dropping a texture directly on an object?

Tags: texturing

I am new to blender and as an experiment I dragged and dropped a texture from the file manager directly to my object in Blender. Now I see a texture on it in when `Solid` or `Texture` Viewport Shading is selected.

[image]

However, after switching to `Rendered` Viewport Shading there is no texture. The object is gray.

[image]

As you can see on the screenshots, the object has no materials or textures in the corresponding panels.

My question is: what happened to the object? Why is there no material/texture when the texture is visible in `Solid` mode? And how do I delete that "ghost" texture so that my object is gray again in `Solid` mode?

Answer (score 1):

The Image you have drop down is present in the UV editor. If you drop down the image editor image you get it.

As soon as you click the image in the UV image editor then you can excess in texture also.

Create a New window -> UV Editor and from there you can find the image from drop down.

Now you can access the image apply to as texture material on the mesh

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't answer all of my questions. I found the image in the UV editor. How do I delete it from there and from the object itself? Also, what happened in Blender internally when I dragged and dropped the image on the object?

Comment: When you drag and drop the image its using UV as image and not the material or texture to the object. When you assign the material or texture to the object then it will be render

Comment: And how do I delete that UV image so that my object is gray again in Solid mode?

Comment: There are different menu options in the UV editor (`Edit Externally`, `Save Image`, `Reload Image`, `Replace Image`, `Open Image`) but there is no `Delete Image` option.

Comment: @user You delete the texture by Shift Clicking on the **X** next to it.